# Expressão regular para obter número entre duas barras

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Tenho um código que pega uma determinada URL, divide ela e me retorna uma lista.

```
url = 'https://www.site.com.br/categoria-produto/category/page/67/? 
gclid=Cjkdksjkcm35522'

last_page = url
if last_page.split("page")[1]:
   t = last_page.split("page")[1]
   print(last_page)
```

Porém a lista, dependendo de como é a URL,  pode ter um valor `/3/` ou `/23/`.

Mas eu não tenho como saber o valor que virá entre essas duas barras,
ou seja uma ou duas posições ou até mesmo três posições.

A única maneira que pensei foi usar expressões regulares, mas não estou sabendo como montar a expressão.

Detalhe: se eu tentar pegar a posição `print(last_page[1:4])` e só tiver 1 casa decimal entre as duas barras, vai pegar a barra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende de como está a URL. Se a URL possui **somente** uma ocorrência de `/page/número/`, uma alternativa é usar [`search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) (do [módulo `re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)):

```
import re

url = 'https://www.site.com.br/categoria-produto/category/page/67/?gclid=Cjkdksjkcm35522'
m = re.search(r'/page/(\d+)', url)
if m:
    print(m[1]) # 67
```

Ou seja, a regex procura por `/page/` e depois verifica se tem um ou mais dígitos (o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d` corresponde a um dígito de 0 a 9, e o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` significa "uma ou mais ocorrências").

O trecho `\d+` está entre parênteses para [formar um grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Assim, eu consigo pegar somente o número, usando `m[1]` (como é o primeiro par de parênteses, então é o primeiro grupo de captura, daí o índice 1).

Se depois do número não tiver necessariamente uma barra (ou seja, a URL pode terminar com `page/67` e não ter mais nada depois), a regex também funciona (`\d+` vai pegando os números até encontrar algum caractere que não seja número, ou o final da string). Mas se quiser pegar o número **somente** se tiver uma barra depois, basta mudar a regex para `r'/page/(\d+)/'` (não sei como estão as URL's que você vai verificar, mas ao usar regex é importante [dizer exatamente o que você quer e o que não quer](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#what_you_want), pois dependendo do caso isso pode fazer diferença).

---

O atalho `+` significa que a quantidade de dígitos pode ser no mínimo 1, e sem limite máximo. Mas se quiser limitar a quantidade, pode usar outras opções:

- `\d{1,10}`: no mínimo 1, no máximo 10 dígitos
- `\d{2,}`: no mínimo 2 dígitos, sem limite máximo
- `\d{2}`: exatamente 2 dígitos

Adapte os valores de acordo com o que você precisar.

---

Obs: o atalho `\d` corresponde a qualquer caractere da [categoria Unicode "Number, Decimal Digit"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm). Isto inclui não apenas os dígitos de 0 a 9, mas também vários outros caracteres que representam dígitos, como por exemplo o `٢` ([ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT TWO](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0662/index.htm)), [entre outros](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm).

Se tais caracteres não ocorrem nas suas URL's, não tem problema usar `\d`. Mas se quiser ser mais específico e considerar apenas os dígitos de 0 a 9, você pode usar a [*flag* ASCII](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.ASCII), ou então usar a [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[0-9]` em vez de `\d`:

```
m = re.search(r'/page/(\d+)/', url, re.ASCII)

# ou

m = re.search(r'/page/([0-9]+)/', url)
```

---

Por fim, o código acima procura apenas pela primeira ocorrência de `/page/número`. Se tiver mais de uma ocorrência e você quiser todas elas, basta usar [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
for m in re.findall(r'/page/(\d+)/', url):
    print(m)
```

Uma característica de `findall` é que, quando os grupos de captura estão presentes, somente estes são retornados. Ou seja, a regex acima já te trará somente os números que aparecem logo depois de `/page/`.

Comment: Muito obrigado.
Bem esclarecedora a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

O código abaixo faz o que você precisa

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re

url = 'https://www.site.com.br/categoria-produto/category/page/67/?gclid=Cjkdksjkcm35522'

re_numbers = r'\/(\d+)(?=\/)'

numbers = re.findall(re_numbers, url)

print(numbers)
```

Ele retorna a lista de números entre duas barras em uma URL. Você pode manipular essa lista e pegar apenas o primeiro, se esse for o caso, ou apenas o último.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, marquei a do @hkotsubo como melhor pois no caso se não tiver barra final ela vai atender também.